# Initial object is limit of identity functor: converse

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

A known theorem in category theory is

> Suppose $\mathscr{C}$ has an initial object $c$. Then $c$, along with
>   its unique maps, forms the limit of the identity functor $\mathscr{C}
>  \to \mathscr{C}$.

It seems like the converse should be true, i.e. if $c$ is a limit of Id then $c$ is initial, but I can't seem to prove it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you know how to formulate limits as initial or terminal objects in some slice or comma category? I don't, but I think I can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(π_c : i → c)_c$ be the limiting cone to $\mathrm{Id}$, and $f : i → c$ a morphism. You want to prove that $f = π_c$. Since $π$ is a cone, we have $π_c = fπ_i$, so it suffices to prove that $π_i = \mathrm{id}$. To do this, use the fact that $π_c$'s are jointly monic: $π_cπ_i = π_c = π_c ∘ \mathrm{id}$ for all $c$, so $π_c = \mathrm{id}$.

Comment: You mean $\pi_i = id$ at the end. Instead of invoking "jointly monic", it seems more direct to say that both $\pi_i$ and $id_i$ induce morphisms of cones; by the uniqueness clause in the definition of limit, this implies $\pi_i = id_i$.